# Is it wise to leave in my current situation?

Tags: interviewing, resignation, career-switch

I am going back to university for a part time masters in computer science, with hopes of moving to the software field. My initial plan was to study in my own time while working and studying part-time, and try to swap to a entry programming job as soon as possible.

I have experience coding in several small projects, but don't have a portfolio or such to apply for jobs like I.e. a front end engineer. I've been having trouble finding the time or energy to finish my own programming projects due to the long hours at my work. I used to study every night and weekend but feel pretty burned out and not really getting anywhere at the moment.

Its become the norm to stay in the office for 10-11 hours a day, and my raise was USD$0.50 per hour so I no longer feel appreciated or have the motivation to stay here any longer. There are also huge upcoming projects that will make it much harder to leave without upsetting my management.

However there is a skillset that only I can do that I self taught, similar to programming, that the upcoming project depends on a lot. Leaving now will make my upper management really upset, as the turnover rate is pretty high as well. I was advised by someone else to negotiate with my leader for a salary increase and shorter working hours to allow me to study. I initially disagree because I don't think they really care and it will just fall on deaf ears, and also because its a famous brand name company, they have no problem getting fresh graduates for low pay.

I guess on one hand its really a no brainer to leave and spend my time pursuing an entry level software development job, but then if I fail to I can't really explain why I'm doing a part time masters and especially with the covid situation, I may be unemployed for a couple months. Essentially I don't know if I'm being rash or being too paranoid and want to cling onto a job that takes too much time and energy just to show that I'm employed and keep the sense of security.

Thank you.

Comment: "Leaving now will make my upper management really upset" and "I initially disagree because I don't think they really care and it will just fall on deaf ears" are contradictory, so which one is it?

Comment: They will be really upset and at the same time reject my request by saying things like it can't be changed, this industry is like that, pay is fixed, while be angry that I'm leaving with this skill that they plan to use. This skill is basically using an difficult program that no one else want to learn, but I picked up quickly.

Comment: "I've been having trouble finding the time or energy to finish my own programming projects due to the long hours at my work." How are you possibly going to do a part-time studies next to your current job if you can't find the time for programming projects as-is?

Answer (score 2):

> There are also huge upcoming projects that will make it much harder to leave without upsetting my management.

That sounds like a managment problem. Having overworked, underpaid staff. From what you write this is exactly what they want. Sorry for the comparision but they want cheap, fresh meat. They're burying the problems with cheap labour.
And if you have something they care about it's THEIR role to keep you. Not yours to make them "not upset/angry" by working in sub-par conditions.

If you finish your masters, you will have a masters. On top of your already aquired skills. Plus you will have time to hone and learn other stuff. THUS making you much more attractive candidate. It will put you in much better position to get new job than to get raise/less-time/promotion in your current work.

Invest in yourself. You are stuck with you for the rest of the time. Your company is not. Maybe in two weeks they decide they prefer to hire 4 post-grads for less than they're paying you. Just because.